# Fringe Search vs A* algorithm in AI

Tags: graph, artificial-intelligence, path-finding

I've been searching on the internet about Fringe search in terms of space and time complexity, but with no success. Can any-one tell me the same and a few points why should we prefer to use fringe search over A* algorithm in artificial intelligence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hadn't explored the fringe search algorithm until seeing this post, so take this with a grain of salt.
According to Wikipedia, [Fringe Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fringe_search) is based off [IDA*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDA*), which in turn is based off [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*).

pros/cons of IDA* over A*:

- IDA* was designed to decrease memory use at the cost of some performance.
- IDA* will check tiles more than once, whereas A* will not
- A* keeps track of *all* tiles instead of just a small subset, like IDA*

So you would choose IDA* over A* if you're more worried about memory consumption than raw speed in returning a path.

Fringe Search vs IDA*/A*:

- Fringe Search is designed to fix some of the worst problems with IDA*, putting it halfway between the two algorithms in terms of performance vs memory usage.
- Should perform faster than IDA*, but perform slower than A*
- More memory usage than IDA*, but less than A*

So, it would seem Fringe Search would be a good choice if you're working with limited memory, but still want more performance than IDA* would provide. In general I would recommend just using A* to start, and if you find you're having any specific issues, finding a substitute algorithm down the road.

Comment: According to the [research paper](http://www.ru.is/~yngvi/pdf/BjornssonEHS05.pdf),  experimental results show that Fringe Search runs roughly 10–40 % faster than highly-optimized A* in their application domain of pathﬁnding on a grid.